# Using in range(..) in an if-else statment

Tags: python

python 2.7

Is it possible to do this:

```
print "Enter a number between 1 and 10:"
number = raw_input("> ")

if number in range(1, 5):
    print "You entered a number in the range of 1 to 5"
elif number in range(6, 10):
    print "You entered a number in the range of 6 to 10"
else:
    print "Your number wasn't in the correct range"
```

I find if I put a number between 1 to 10 it always falls to the else statement.

Is this an incorrect use of in range in an if-else statement?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Note that `range(1,5)` does not include the number 5.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is because the input data is string. So it flows to else. Convert it into integer then all will be fine.

```
>>> number = raw_input("> ")
>>> type(number)
<type 'str'>
int(number) converts to <type 'int'>
```

Please use:

```
if int(number) in range(1, 6):
    print "You entered a number in the range of 1 to 5"
elif int(number) in range(6, 11):
    print "You entered a number in the range of 6 to 10"
else:
    print "Your number wasn't in the correct range"
```

Comment: `int("5") in range(1, 5)` -> `False`

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> number = raw_input()
3
>>> type(number)
<type 'str'>
>>> "3" in range(1,5)
False


number = int(raw_input())
```

Answer (score 4):

You should convert the input (which is a string) into a number first before you check it. You should also use `if 1 < number <= 5:`, no need to create a list just to check if a number is within a range.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, the `in` operator may be used as a boolean operator testing for attribute membership. It is hence usable in an  `if..else` statement (see below for the full documentation extract).

When using the `in` operator, (e.g `obj in container`) the interpreter first looks if `container` has a  `__contains__` method. If it does not but if the `container` defines the `__iter__` method, python will then iterate on all values contained in the object and test for equality i.e. it will basically perform something like

```
for value in container:
    if value == obj:
        return True
return False
```

Finally, if neither methods are defined, the interpreter looks for the `__getitem__` method to iterate over the container and would still test for equality of any value with `obj`.
You may also look at [the comparison operator documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__).

Now, in your case, the `range([start], stop[, step])` function [[documentation]](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) actually returns a list (beware that this list does **not** hold the last element so `range(1, 5) == [1, 2, 3, 4]`), which defines the `__contains__` method:

```
>>> type(range(1, 10))
list
>>> hasattr(list, '__contains__')
True
>>> 4 in range(1, 10)
True
```

so this is perfectly authorized to write `x in range(1, 10)`. As other answers point out, your problem is actually a type problem solved by casting the input data into an integer (as `"3" == 3` is False).
However, if you solely intend to test if the input value is properly bounded, I would definitively recommend you to use comparison operator

```
>>> if 1 <= x < 10:
...     print 'ok'
... else:
...     print 'ko'
```

as it looks more readable *and* you are not constructing an obsolete list so you would minimize your memory footprint.

Note that to avoid the implicit construction of the list, you could use the `xrange` function that returns an iterator rather than a list and that in this case, as values are evaluated lazily, `xrange` does not define the `__contains__` method but it defines the `__iter__` method so everything would still work fine!

```
>>> type(xrange(1, 10))
xrange
>>> hasattr(xrange, '__contains__')
False
>>> hasattr(xrange, '__iter__')
True
>>> 4 in xrange(1, 10)
True
```

Finally, here is the extract from the python documentation about [`in` operator](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#in)

> The operators in and not in test for collection membership. x in s evaluates to true if x is a member of the collection s, and false otherwise. x not in s returns the negation of x in s. The collection membership test has traditionally been bound to sequences; an object is a member of a collection if the collection is a sequence and contains an element equal to that object. However, it make sense for many other object types to support membership tests without being a sequence. In particular, dictionaries (for keys) and sets support membership testing.
>
> For the list and tuple types, x in y is true if and only if there exists an index i such that x == y[i] is true.
>
> For the Unicode and string types, x in y is true if and only if x is a substring of y. An equivalent test is y.find(x) != -1. Note, x and y need not be the same type; consequently, u'ab' in 'abc' will return True. Empty strings are always considered to be a substring of any other string, so "" in "abc" will return True.
>
> Changed in version 2.3: Previously, x was required to be a string of length 1.
>
> For user-defined classes which define the `__contains__`() method, x in y is true if and only if y.`__contains__`(x) is true.
>
> For user-defined classes which do not define `__contains__`() but do define `__iter__`(), x in y is true if some value z with x == z is produced while iterating over y. If an exception is raised during the iteration, it is as if in raised that exception.
>
> Lastly, the old-style iteration protocol is tried: if a class defines `__getitem__`(), x in y is true if and only if there is a non-negative integer index i such that x == y[i], and all lower integer indices do not raise IndexError exception. (If any other exception is raised, it is as if in raised that exception).
>
> The operator not in is defined to have the inverse true value of in.
>
> The operators is and is not test for object identity: x is y is true if and only if x and y are the same object. x is not y yields the inverse truth value. [7]

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to use int in the beginning:

```
number = int(raw_input("> "))
```

Answer (score 1):

[try in Online](https://onlinegdb.com/9q_cdU37V)

in python3

```
print ("Enter a number between 1 and 10:")
number = int(input( ))



if int(number) in range(1, 6):
   print ("You entered a number in the range of 1 to 5")
elif int(number) in range(6, 11):
    print ("You entered a number in the range of 6 to 10")
else:
    print ("Your number wasn't in the correct range")
```

Results:

```
Enter a number between 1 and 10:
4
You entered a number in the range of 1 to 5
```

Comment: How is this answer different from the accepted one?

Answer (score -2):

print ("Enter a number between 1 and 10:")

number = int(input("Enter a number: "))

if number in range(1, 5):

```
print ("You entered a number in the range of 1 to 5")
```

elif number in range(6, 10):

```
print ("You entered a number in the range of 6 to 10")
```

else:

```
print ("Your number wasn't in the correct range")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).